# jQuery - find all inputs, except the ones descending from div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Well I'm trying to write a validation jQuery plugin, but for that I need to find all inputs inside of a container, which is marked with an attribute. However, that container may have other sub-containers, also marked with attributes, and they may have their own inputs.

I need to select all inputs, descendants of the parent container (accessed by $(this)) which are not descendants of the sub-containers. Is that possible?

Some code to illustrate:

```
<div data-container>
    <input>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input>
    </div>
    <input>
    <div data-container>
        <input>
        <input>
        <input>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to select those first three inputs, and ignore the ones inside the children data-container. The one inside the form-group must be selected too.

Comment: Can you not use class='required', then use $.each() to go through the form?

Comment: using classes like @Pete suggested makes much more sense

Comment: Sure, but I'm trying to create an easy validation system not only for required fields, but numeric, alphanumeric, min-size, email, date, and others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) to exclude a selection from an existing jQuery selection:

```
var yourSelection = $(this).find('input').not($(this).find('[data-container] input'));
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NgfZy/) (I replaced the `$(this)` by `$('[data-container]:first')` in the fiddle for simplicity)

Comment: @gustavo, don't you think you should upvote the answer :) really neat.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, here http://jsfiddle.net/2Wv7P/

```
$('div[data-container] input:lt(3)')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this must work in any situation and not only in this example, so we can't assure that it will be the first three inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You can select based on the parent div like this. Only the first level children are going to be selected based on you given tag, assuming you ID the parent div as #parent

```
$('#parent > input')
```

So following this path, if you have to select the parent with $(this), which is to say using 'this', then you can select this same set of 'input's using

```
$('#' + this.id + ' > input')
```

For example
[see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tafhim/SumLd/2/)

Comment: I understand, but some inputs may not be direct children, like the one inside the form-group div.